# IPC passing for Linux User space exe

Tags: ipc, embedded-linux

We have a programme, lets call it Y.exe. It runs on an embedded system and it runs without exiting (i.e. the system starts, loads the Linux kernel, all the kernel modules, then Y.exe, and Y never returns (user space)).

Now there comes a time when we are required to change how Y.exe is running i.e. turn on some debug, make it take certain other code routes for tests, etc.

The current way of doing this is to compile, and recompile Y to handle each test. This seems like a waist of time and we should be able to dynamically set the conditions.

I would love to use something like the proc/debug system from the kernel where you can simply do something like:

```
echo 1 > /proc/test_y
```

to enable tests, etc.

Seeing that the proc/debug are kernel level items, they cannot be used for user space executables(?).

Apart from implementing a full on IPC through message Q's or TCP, are there any other ways to implement similar functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it check for the existence of a flag file somewhere through each event loop iteration?

Set a signal handler for `SIGUSR1`?  `SIGUSR2`?

Upon any of these occurring, set a flag value in the program that will perform the tests or output the debugging information, and then is toggled after receiving another, or the flag file disappearing, etc.

Something like the above should achieve similar functionality to what you're talking about.  The signals would be more immediate (and probably more straightforward), but either mechanism should be sufficient.

Comment: Can you send these signals via the command line at all? The idea is to have flags, etc. that can control the functionality using the likely/unlikely gcc opts to make less run time impact.

Comment: Yeah, `kill -USR1 PID` will do it.  `kill -l` lists the possible signals available.  `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be trapped.  `man 7 signal` gives more information about the various signals ad their default behaviors.  You'll probably want to use the functions `signal` (and possibly `sigaction`) to work with them, if you're not already familiar with it.

Comment: Note that there are only 2 user-level signals (though some people also hook `SIGHUP` and others), so if you want more than that, you may also consider using a named pipe to pass specific commands for what debugging information to enable (and with something like that naturally comes more complexity.)

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot the other part. we need quite a few indications to control all the modules...so maybe signals is not such a good idea. I assume that there are no ways of passing arguments to the signals?

Comment: Not that way.  To pass information beyond this, a named pipe that you can just write simple commands to, that the running process opens and watches the other end at start and on each event loop iteration will probably be best.  You can do it with a flag file, as well, but a named pipe automatically gives you a pure FIFO (though you probably still want to `flock` the writing side), whereas a flag file would have to be more carefully controlled for race conditions.

Comment: Ah, ok. I am really not clued up on pipes. But would we be talking about the | on the command line? or needing to implement a separate programme to send the information?

Comment: No, when you call `mkfifo`, it just creates a node in the filesystem at the specified location; then, you can open it for reading (in the server process), and poll/select on it through each event loop (probably with O_NONBLOCK), and read it if data becomes available.  Since you want to load specified modules, I'd just come up with some simple commands to pass it like "LOAD modname" and "UNLOAD modname" or something.  From the other end, you can just `echo LOAD module > pipefname` to it like a normal file.

Comment: You can wrap all this in `#ifdef` statements or whatever for conditional compilation to get rid of the logic in production.  Signals would be more immediate, but this would work fine.  Your original question only mentioned a flag, not a complex module loading/unloading facility, which is why I went with the original solution, btw. ;-)

Comment: P.S. `mkfifo` is both a cmdline tool and library call.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, the original example is a bit simplistic. The pipe looks like a good solution. The signal is a great bit of knowledge to remember :)

Comment: Cheers, mate.  HTH.  (Had to go to the store, hence the 30 minute delay ;)  Pipe will obviously be more involved, but since you need additional functionality, it seems the best solution.